# g++ - Disabling link-time warning originating in external lib

Tags: c++, oracle, warnings, ld, glibc

I'm getting the following warning at link-time:

```
/opt/oracle/11.2.0.3/lib/libclntst11.a(cc_memory.o): In function `krb5_mcc_generate_new':
cc_memory.c:(text.unlikely+0xd3d): warning: the use of `mktemp' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
```

I link with `g++ [...] -L/opt/oracle/11.2.0.3/lib -lclntst11 [...]

Is there a way to hide this warning?
It's polluting the build logs (got dozens of executables which use the Oracle client).

I know about `-isystem` to decrease the number of warnings coming from external libs but that's for headers only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the following somewhere in my program (not in a library it links to):

```
// to silence warnings when linking to libwhatever.a
extern "C" char* mktemp(char*) { __builtin_abort(); }
```

The linker will use that definition in preference to the one in libc.so ... **but** this is only OK if the library never actually calls `mktemp`! In my case I know I'm linking to a library that refers to it, but I never use the feature that calls it.  If code used by your program does call `mktemp` then it will abort.

Another alternative would be to provide your own definition of `mktemp`, possibly implemented using `mkstemp` and removing the file it creates, although that still has the same dangerous race condition that `mktemp` has (`mktemp` is basically a broken API.)

You should complain to Oracle for providing a library that relies on a broken API.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. Quality answer as always.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to hide this warning?

Sure: rebuild your `libc` from source to remove it [*warning*: this may require root priviledges and can render your system *unbootable* if done incorrectly].

Why do you want to, though? If you understand the warning and choose to ignore it, then ... ignore it?

If you don't understand the warning, you should.